# Angular2 communication between 2 components

Tags: data-binding, angular, typescript

i am using Angular2 rc5 and i try to build a component communication through a service.
For arrays it works like expected but if i change a string its not updating.

My main component looks like:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ShareServiceService} from "../share-service.service";
import {ChildTwoComponent} from "../child-two/child-two.component";
import {ChildOneComponent} from "../child-one/child-one.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <div>
            <child-one></child-one>
            <child-two></child-two>
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [ShareServiceService],
    directives: [ChildOneComponent, ChildTwoComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

My first children component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ShareServiceService} from "../share-service.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'child-one',
    template: `
        <div style="float:right; width: 45%">
            <pre>title: {{title}}</pre>
            <pre>title: {{_sharedService.testTitle}}</pre>
            <div>
            <ul *ngFor="let dataElement of data">
                <li>{{dataElement}}</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
    })
export class ChildOneComponent{
    data:string[] = [];
    title:string;

    constructor(public _sharedService:ShareServiceService) {
        this.data = this._sharedService.dataArray;
        this.title = this._sharedService.testTitle;
    }
}
```

The second children component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ShareServiceService} from "../share-service.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'child-two',
    template: `
        <div style="float:left; width: 45%">
            <pre>title: {{title}}</pre>
            <pre>titleObj: {{titleObj.title}}</pre>
            <div>
                <ul *ngFor="let dataElement of data">
                    <li>{{dataElement}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dataInput"/>
        <button (click)="addData()">addData</button>
        <button (click)="updateTitle()">updateTitle</button>
        </div>
        `
})
export class ChildTwoComponent {
    dataInput:string = 'Testing data';
    data:string[] = [];
    title:string;

    constructor(public _sharedService:ShareServiceService) {
        this.data = this._sharedService.dataArray;
        this.title = this._sharedService.testTitle;
    }

    addData() {
        this._sharedService.insertData(this.dataInput);
        this.dataInput = '';
    }

    updateTitle() {
        this._sharedService.updateTestTitle(this.dataInput);
        this.dataInput = '';
    }
}
```

My service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ShareServiceService {
    dataArray:string[] = [];
    testTitle:string = "should be updated";

    insertData(data:string) {
        this.dataArray.push(data);
    }

    updateTestTitle(newTitle:string) {
        this.testTitle = {title: newTitle};
    }
}
```

What i try to achieve is, that if i enter something in the input field with binding for "" and press the "updateTitle" that the Title in both components are updated.
But thats doesnt work currently.

if i add my input value to an array, by clicking the "adddata" Button, all works like excepted and my list with data elements shows all elements.

Does someone know why i cant update a string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy an object or array you copy a reference. Both (source and destination) point to the same object. If one side modifies the object the other side sees the modification.

If you copy a primitive value (string, number, boolean), the the destination gets a copy of the value and source and destination aren't related in any way.

```
   // copies a reference
   this.data = this._sharedService.dataArray;
   // copies the value
   this.title = this._sharedService.testTitle;
```

What you probably want is an observable that emits events when properties in the shared service are modified.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service